# How to align two sentence that has the same named entity category using Stanford NER in python?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm going to align two different sentences that contain the same NER categories ('PERSON','LOCATION','ORGANIZATION') using stanford NER in python.

```
sentence1 = John is reading a booklet in London Library
sentence2 = Michael reads a brochure in England Library
```

what I want as the result is like this :

```
result= [[[u'John', u'Person'],[u'Michael',u'PERSON']] , [[u'London',u'LOCATION],['u'England',u'LOCATION']]]
```

I have tried with my codes

```
def alignNER(self, sent1, sent2):
    java.path = 'C:/program files'/java/jre/bin/java.exe'
    os.environ ['JAVAHOME'] = java.path
    st = StanfordNERTagger('usr/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser','usr/stanford-ner.jar')

    result = []
    for i in xrange(len(sent1)):
        if sent1[i]:
            word = sent1[i]
            temp = st.tag(word.split())
            for token, tag in temp:
                if tag in ['PERSON','LOCATION','ORGANIZATION']:
                    result.append([temp,i])
    return result

    for j in xrange(len(sent2)):
        if sent2[j]:
            word = sent2[j]
            temp = st.tag(word.split())
            for token, tag in temp:
                if tag in ['PERSON','LOCATION','ORGANIZATION']:
                    result.append([temp,j])
    return result
```

and when I call it

```
checkNER = alignNER(sent1, sent2)
print checkNER
```

the result only shows the sentence 1 with the position index of detected categories :

```
[[[u'John', u'Person'],0],[[u'London',u'LOCATION],6]]
```

anybody can help? thanks

Comment: You return the output `result` twice. Can you fix the indentation first?

Comment: but there is no indentation error on that code

Comment: it's not indentation error. however, you cannot return `result` twice

Comment: So i only can return result once? which "result" I should delete and where is the indentation I should fix, sir?

Comment: you should have `result1`, `result2` and `return result1, result2` as an output.